# adding https website to trusted list using C sharp

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, https, registry, trusted-sites

I need to write c sharp application which can mimic IE functionality of adding websites to trusted list, I am able to achieve this however when it comes to require HTTPS checkbox implementation, my code is not working.

```
private void checkHTTP_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.checkHTTP.Checked)
    {
        saveHTTPSSettings(71);
    }
    else
    {
        saveHTTPSSettings(67);
    }
}

private void saveHTTPSSettings(int val)
{
     RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
        @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2\");

     if (key != null)
     {
         key.SetValue("Flags", val);
     }
}
```

After doing this registery gets changed same as IE trusted site HTTPS option does, but when it comes to add websites, it does not work as intended. it add both sites sometime no matter what is selected for https and sometime gives error with error code -2147024891

Answer (score 1):

The error you receive translates as hex code  **0x80070005** that means you don't have enough permission to do what you want. Try to launch your program with right click/run as administrator to see if something change.

Comment: Tried as run as administrator, still getting the same error code.